# How to make a variable inside a function that saves its value from call to call

Tags: java

I want to know how and if I can define a variable inside a function and accumulate its value in each call. For example:

```
public int foo(int num, int cost){
     int sum;
     sum += num*cost;
     System.out.println("all costs are "+ sum);
     return sum; 
}
```

I want the variable `sum` to accumulate its value from one call to another so that the following calls:

```
foo(5,3);
foo(2,8);
```

Will print this output:

```
all costs are 15
all costs are 31
```

Can I do this with java? And if yes then how do I do that.
I am sorry I don't know the concept I am trying to implements. I know that in other languages it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is creating `new object of type int` having the same name `sum`every time you call the method `foo()`. As, you are creating new object the previous value will be overwritten.

But you want to save the value for later use. So, to achieve this you have to change the `scope` of the variable and declare it outside the functions. So, that every method can use it and it can save its previous value.

Working Code:

```
public class stackInt
{
    public static int sum=0;  // now every method can access this variable
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        foo(5,3);
        foo(2,8);
    }

    // according to your output you dont have to set return type as "int"
    public static void foo(int num, int cost)
    {
        sum += num*cost;
        System.out.println("all costs are "+ sum); 
        //return sum; as you have printed the output what you want, so, no need to return "sum"
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In Printing you are using `cost` but according to output it should be `sum`, moreover, no need to return `sum` if you goal is to just print it.

Comment: Question - is there any meaning to why you chose to make foo a static method?

Comment: @Netta if I don't do that it won't compile the reason is that "we can't call a `non-static` method from a `static context`" as, main method is static. You can remove the `static` from `foo()` and see what happens, it'll give you a clearer picture.

Comment: If you want to make `foo()` non-static, then you have to make an object like `stackInt object = new stackInt()`. After this you can call `foo()` by `dot operator` like `object.foo(5,3)`. Now remove `static` from `foo()` and it'll work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

in java you can add variables on classes so it would look something like this:

```
int sum=0;

public int foo(int num, int cost){

 sum += num*cost;
 System.out.println("all costs are "+ cost);
 return sum; 
}
```

the variable will then only be reset for every instance you make of the class the foo method is on

if you want to persist it across different instances as well you can do

```
static int sum=0;
```

instead

Comment: And if I make sum a static would it work inside foo?

Comment: no you cant declare static variables in method bodies

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a global variable outside of the function that keeps track of the variable.

Like this:

```
private int sum = 0;

public int foo(int num, int cost){

    sum = sum + num * cost;
    System.out.println("all costs are "+ cost);
    return sum; 
}
```

If you define `int sum;` inside the method, each time the method is called it will overwrite the variable which is not what you want in your case.